# Groups of equi-quasi-isometric diffeomorphisms of a Riemannian surface of bounded geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $M$ be an open Riemannian surface of bounded geometry. Let $\Gamma$ be a group of diffeomorphisms of $M$. Suppose that $\Gamma$ is equi-quasi-isometric; i.e., its elements are (differentiable) quasi-isometries with a common bound of dilation. Consider the action of $\Gamma$ on $L^2$ harmonic $1$-forms on $M$ defined by $\gamma\cdot\alpha=\Pi\gamma^*\alpha$, where $\Pi$ denotes the orthogonal projection of the space of $L^2$ $1$-forms to the space of harmonic ones. Assume that this action commutes with the Hodge star operator. Are the elements of $\Gamma$ isotopic to conformal maps?

The following question may be helpful to solve the previous one. Let $\operatorname{Mod}(M)$ denote the mapping class group of $M$, $I(M)\subset\operatorname{Mod}(M)$ the Torelli subgroup, and $\bar\Gamma\subset\operatorname{Mod}(M)$ the subgroup defined by $\Gamma$. Is it true that $\bar\Gamma\cap I(M)=\{1\}$ when $\Gamma$ is equi-quasi-isometric?

Comment: Answer to the 2nd question is positive since every equiquisiusomereuc group preserves some conformal structure and hence is finite (assuming genus at least 2).